# Visual Basic Resources

Tags: vb.net, audio, resources

Ok my question is simple. I have 3 resources in my Visual Basic project in visual studio, all are audio files. I want my application to play the sound whose name the user typed in a TextBox.

To explain a bit further:
I have the resources "Fire", "Water" and "Air". If the user types Air in a textbox, then I use

```
My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Air, AudioPlayMode.Background)
```

But I don't want to make a copy of the code for each possibility, I just want to make it into a variable to be played as an object. Can anyone help me? :s

Comment: Use My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject() instead.  It takes a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably put this into a case statement

```
 Dim ResourceFilePathPrefix As String 
    If System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached() Then 
        'In Debugging mode     
        ResourceFilePathPrefix = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(Application.StartupPath & "\..\..\resources\")  
    Else 
        'In Published mode     
        ResourceFilePathPrefix = Application.StartupPath & "\resources\" 
    End If 

    'you name your files Fire.wav, Water.wav or whatever you want.
    playerStream = ResourceFilePathPrefix & textBox1.text + ".wav"

    My.Computer.Audio.Play(playerStream, AudioPlayMode.Background)
```

or you could reference it directly:

```
Try
  My.Computer.Audio.Play("C:\TEST\" & textBox1.text,AudioPlayMode.Background)
Catch ex As Exception
  MsgBox("The file does not exist." & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
End Try
```

assuming your wav files are @ c:\test :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that would be hard if I've got, for example, 200 audio files to be played. Isn't there another way to do it?

Comment: Check out the modification, I've added textBox1.text for the wav

Comment: You just simply name your files you want into Resources and append the .wav at the end of it. I think this should work.

Comment: I've added a try catch below that may be easier for your purposes, It uses Audio.Play and the file path directly instead of using resources in your project.

Comment: Oh the suggestion to add .wav at the end of the files did quite what I needed. Thank you :D

Comment: Wrap it in a try/catch like below if you like too. That way you can handle the error if the user enters a textBox1.text that doesn't exist and give them a slap on the hand with a nice msgbox! :)